# PostSharp throws error in VS 2015 but not in VS 2013 when building

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, postsharp

I have an enterprise level solution of WPF with multiple projects.  The code builds fine in VS 2013, in VS 2015 the code does not build.

I have tried:

1. Removing the project affected and tweaking code to observe it is just this project.  It is.
2. I tried using the NuGet Manager to remove the PostSharp references of 'PostSharp', 'PostSharp.Patterns.Common', 'PostSharp.Patterns.Model'; rebuild, restart VS, get latest from Nuget.  Same exception.
3. I tried upgrading all other projects.  Same story.

In the solution I also have references to 'Prism' and 'Unity' both by MS.  The problem is that I do not even know 'where' this is occurring and am just flying blind as the stack trace error just mentions the project and not a specific class or location other than references to 'PostSharp' namespaces.  It is this:

```
'Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       An unexpected exception occurred when executing user code: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.DependencyAnalysis.PropertiesDependenciesAnalyzer.MethodAnalyzer.TryGetDependsOn(IMethodCallExpression expression, List`1& invocationPaths, List`1& messages)
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.DependencyAnalysis.PropertiesDependenciesAnalyzer.MethodAnalyzer.VisitMethodCallExpression(IMethodCallExpression expression)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitSyntaxElement(ISyntaxElement syntaxElement)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitStatementExpression(IStatementExpression statementExpression)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitSyntaxElement(ISyntaxElement syntaxElement)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitBlockExpression(IBlockExpression instructionBlock)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitSyntaxElement(ISyntaxElement syntaxElement)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitBlockExpression(IBlockExpression instructionBlock)
   at PostSharp.Reflection.Syntax.SyntaxTreeVisitor.VisitMethodBody(ISyntaxMethodBody methodBody)
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.DependencyAnalysis.PropertiesDependenciesAnalyzer.MethodAnalyzer.AnalyzeMethodRecursive(MethodBase method)
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.DependencyAnalysis.PropertiesDependenciesAnalyzer.MethodAnalyzer.AnalyzeProperty(Type type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ExplicitDependencyMap currentTypeExplicitDependencyMap)
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChanged.DependencyAnalysis.PropertiesDependenciesAnalyzer.AnalyzeType(Type type)
   at PostSharp.Patterns.Model.NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute.CompileTimeInitialize(Type type, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeavers.TypeLevelAspectWeaverInstance.^RDzfO2to.^XTF+fjOj()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Utilities.ExceptionHelper.ExecuteUserCode(MessageLocation messageLocation, Action userCode, Type[] acceptableExceptions).   Namespace.Project D:\TFS\SourceCodeLocation\POSTSHARP
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was something very very simple that was somehow allowed by VS 2013 and 2015 even with Compile option of 'strict' set to on but PostSharp would not.

```
Private _DateDeactivated As Nullable(Of Date)

<SafeForDependencyAnalysis>
Public Property DateDeactivated As Nullable(Of Date)
  Get
    If MyRequest.DateDeactivated.HasValue Then
      IsDeactivated = True
        Return MyRequest.DateDeactivated.Value
      Else
        Return New Nullable(Of Date)
      End If
    End Get
  Set(value As Nullable(Of Date))
    _DateDeactivated = value
  End Set
End Property
```

This line

```
Return MyRequest.DateDeactivated.Value
```

Should simply be:

```
Return MyRequest.DateDeactivated
```

It was not my code but was causing a larger solution to not compile with PostSharp in VS 2015.  I was more concerned that PostSharp could not provide a reference to the actual file.  I figured it out with the brute force of just going through the files and commenting out properties and methods till I got a build success and then went through the files till I found what was wrong.  There are probably better tools for validation like ReSharper that may have caught it, but it works.  This may help someone, may not.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in `[NotifyPropertyChanged]` aspect and should be fixed in releases 4.2.26 and 4.3.9. Please let me know if it is not the case.

The problem was in the way VB compiler generates IL code for handling `Nullable<T>` - the analysis for property dependencies simply did not expect that.